# Long boot time due to loader

Tags: boot, dual-boot, uefi

My system is taking way too long to boot up since I installed ubuntu. I have a dual boot with windows 10 on a reasonably fast notebook. After selecting the OS on the grub menu, it goes to a purple screen and stays on it for a long time.

So I did what was suggested [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/850787/gnu-grub-menu-takes-too-long-to-boot) and enabled messaging to see what the system was doing. But the messages take way too long to show up as well.

Here's the output of my **systemd-analyze blame**:

```
     51.299s dev-sda7.device
     32.721s systemd-journal-flush.service
     28.578s dev-loop1.device
     28.171s dev-loop3.device
     27.975s dev-loop0.device
     27.944s dev-loop2.device
     27.911s dev-loop4.device
     20.064s systemd-sysctl.service
     18.802s dev-loop5.device
     18.610s systemd-udevd.service
     18.514s dev-loop6.device
     18.023s dev-loop7.device
     15.873s snap-gnome\x2dcalculator-180.mount
     15.196s user@1000.service
     14.727s snap-core-4917.mount
     13.695s snap-gnome\x2dsystem\x2dmonitor-51.mount
     13.433s NetworkManager-wait-online.service
     12.623s snap-gnome\x2dlogs-37.mount
     11.263s snap-gtk\x2dcommon\x2dthemes-319.mount
     11.219s snap-gnome\x2d3\x2d26\x2d1604-70.mount
     11.208s snap-core-5145.mount
      9.864s ModemManager.service
      7.825s snapd.service
```

And here is the output of **systemd-analyze time**

```
Startup finished in 49.498s (firmware) + 5min 14.605s (loader) + 5.855s (kernel) + 1min 21.736s (userspace) = 7min 31.696s
```

So i guess my problem is with the loader. Any ideas?